# SHARP Aquos 104sh moves cursor to wrong location

Tags: text-input, text-prediction

I'm trying to edit and questions on stackoverflow, but when I click to move the cursor to a location or reselect a word, the cursor winds up far north of my click point. I need to do some more testing to see if it is a fixed distance.  It seems to be fixed, instance-by-instance, but variable overall.

**-Edit-**

I noticed that this isn't happening consistently, which makes it difficult to reproduce and test; however, it seems to become worse as the text grows longer.

I've widdled it down to Dolphin, for one.  It doesn't happen with Jota++, but it may happen in my S!Mail, sometimes.  I'm using the TouchPal Keypad (Swype), Dolphin Browser.  I think that it has something to do with TouchPal.